# Join adjacent polygons of an SPDF using gTouches?

Tags: r, polygon

I'm trying to join adjacent polygons in a SpatialPointsDataFrame without merging the whole SPDF into one. 
The SPDF is a glacier shapefile with some of the glaciers separated into different polygons. I want to merge these adjacent polygons.

I tried `merge`and `aggregate`, but this merges every polygon together and results in a SpatialPolygon-object and the @data slot is lost.

Is it possible to merge just the adjacent polygons using for example the IDs of adjacent polygons (as given by `gTouches`) and keeping the whole thing as a SPDF with the @data slot?`

EDIT: 
I've converted my data to an sf-object as proposed by Bernd and managed to merge the polygons.

My next question would be:
[How to delete parts of a multipolygon inside an sf-object in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327683/how-to-delete-parts-of-a-multipolygon-inside-an-sf-object-in-r)

Comment: Is there as specific reason not to use the sf package and convert your data to sf-objects? Especially data handling there is so much more convenient.