# How to delete parts of a multipolygon inside an sf-object in R?

Tags: r, polygon

I have spatial data (about some glaciers) as an sf-object. My shp-file can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT

Some of the glaciers are separated into different polygons. In the end, I want to resolve the inner boundaries and delete all polygons who are smaller than a certain cutoff (lets say 0,05km²).

So far I managed to merge adjacent polygons using `st_union`

```
glaciers <- readOGR("C:/***", "Glacier_Clip_Polygon")  
glaciers_sf <- st_as_sf(glaciers)
glaciers_combined <- st_union(glaciers_sf)
```

Merging them results in a Multipolygon with all inner boundaries resolved. So far so good. It now looks like this:

```
> glaciers_comb
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 81.38991 ymin: 42.47015 xmax: 81.54986 ymax: 42.57237
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
MULTIPOLYGON (((81.46754 42.47274, 81.46791 42....
```

But now I don't know how to address the polygons separately or how to delete the ones with an area smaller than my cutoff. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST them to POLYGON, giving 38 features:

```
> gg = st_cast(glaciers_combined,"POLYGON")
> gg
Geometry set for 38 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 81.38991 ymin: 42.47015 xmax: 81.54986 ymax: 42.57237
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
POLYGON ((81.46754 42.47274, 81.46791 42.47296,...
POLYGON ((81.45238 42.47778, 81.4526 42.47779, ...
POLYGON ((81.4409 42.47899, 81.44092 42.47898, ...
POLYGON ((81.41139 42.48442, 81.41071 42.48446,...
POLYGON ((81.41643 42.48445, 81.41637 42.48485,...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it.